# Swiper is not working after merge the code from main branch

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

This is the code i am using in html file

```
  <swiper-container [pagination]="true">
    @for (user of userList; track $index;) {
    <swiper-slide class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <ion-card class="mt0 ml0 mr0">
        <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
        <img
          class="object-fit-cover"
          width="420"
          height="220"
          [src]="user?.img"
          alt=""
        />

        <div
          class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 position-absolute pdb16 px-3 bottom-0"
        >
          <div class="pdl-h3 pdl-clr-white pdb6">
            {{ user.padelCourtName }}
          </div>
          <div class="pdl-h3 d-flex text-end bold pdl-clr-white">
            ${{ user.price }}/h
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-card>
    </swiper-slide>
    }
  </swiper-container>
```

and the ts code is

```
userList: any[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        padelCourtName: 'Padel Court Name 1',
        price: '50',
        img: '../../assets/court-img.jpg',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        padelCourtName: 'Padel Court Name 1',
        price: '50',
        img: '../../assets/court-img.jpg',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        padelCourtName: 'Padel Court Name 1',
        price: '50',
        img: '../../assets/court-img.jpg',
    },
];
```

I also import the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and schemas for this when i am using this  before the merge code it is work properly and now i merge the the code to my branch from the main branch and there is no error in console. What should i do?

I also ask the Chatgpt and it is told me to check the data but it is also not working

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say based on information you provided, but since there is no error in your template nor data, here are my guesses:

1. I don't see register() function. use it like this:

   import {register} from 'swiper/element/bundle';

   constructor() {
   register();
   }
2. Use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA properly

   @Component({
   ...
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
   })
3. Make sure you have proper version of swiper installed in package.json